# 1 image 2 links

Tags: html, bitmap, imagemap, expression-web

how do you make an image be clickable in in HTML in different areas of the image and lead to different URL's... for instance I have an image or "button" if you will that is 1 image but I want it to actually be 2 links... one side of the button is "sign up" while the other side is "try out"

Comment: Strictly out of curiosity, any reason not to cut the image up in an image editing program and have 2 images, each with their own anchors?  The image map (suggested below) will work fine.  Like I said, just curious :)

Comment: For one, multiple images means multiple requests by the browser. Hence for example, if you have images for a list of numbers like 1 to 10 (in pagination), its better to have single image with an image map.

Comment: If you are using images "for a list of numbers like 1 to 10", then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I do agree :). However, just for sake of extending the argument, what if I want a fancy font AND do not want to depend on browser font support. Or if I am developing some non-english language pages and again don't want to depend on client having the right fonts. There are of course better examples for justifying image maps but as you can imagine, I just wanted to  protect my stance having been caught off-gaurd ;)

Comment: @JP19: You can use CSS sprites and you only do 1 request to the server.

Comment: @nico: Sounds cool. Need to learn it! Of late, I am concerned about reducing number of requests when user visits my site for the first time (too many js/css/image request as of now).

Comment: @JP19: Have a look at this ALA article: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

Comment: @JP -FWIW, I wasn't trying to start an argument, nor was I trying to catch you "off guard". Sorry if you took it that way. I was just genuinely curious about your rationale. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use CSS-sprites

I think that the best way is to use CSS sprite: http://www.jsfiddle.net/pereskokov/vVhde/1/.
Main benefit of using it — your image will not be a part of content, it's just decor. So your content will be *accessible*. Also you can easy change decoration of your site via css and use another image.

Using `map` is justified only when image is part of content — for exemple, it is [real map](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html) :)

### HTML

```
<a href="#login" title="Log In" id="login"><span></span>Log In</a>
<a href="#signin" title="Sign In" id="signin"><span></span>Sign In</a>
```

### CSS

```
#login, #signin {
    width: 50px;
    height: 27px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#login span {
    width: 50px;
    height: 27px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5988007/sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

#signin span {
    width: 50px;
    height: 27px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5988007/sprite.png) -50px 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Use HTML image maps: http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml

Example:

```
<img src="button.gif" usemap="#yourmap" border="0">
<map name="yourmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,50,50" href="http://www.yoursite.com/link1.html">
<area shape="rect" coords="50, 0, 100, 100" href="http://www.yoursite.com/link2.html">
</map>
```

Comment: You can also create arbitrary polygons, circles, etc instead of rectangles.

Comment: Check this out too: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap maybe it will come in handy.