# on click of part of image redirect to many urls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I use PHP and I am trying to have a redirect on click of part of an image. I will have one image and if I click on a part of this image I will redirect the user to the new URL.

Something like this image:
[image]

If one of these icons is clicked I must redirect to a page with products. I can not use google maps, the client wants it to be an image ...

Maybe be with jquery? Can anyone please guide me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1 image 2 links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305109/1-image-2-links)

Comment: Well yes, you can use jquery. But you can also look at `<map>` HTML element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a good old image map:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

And use a generator to make it:
https://www.image-map.net/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set pin icons separately from the image. After that you need to set respective links on respective icons.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use CSS. Have the image as a background of a relatively positioned parent, then use absolutely positioned children

**SASS**

```
ul {
  background: transparent url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEzZR.png) center center;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  li {
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    &:nth-child(1){top:10px; left:50px;}
    &:nth-child(2){top:100px; left:33px;}
    &:nth-child(3){top:60px; left:290px;}
    a {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 30px;
      width: 20px;
      text-indent: -9999px;
      background-color:red;
    }
  }
}
```

See this example - https://jsfiddle.net/tgd7wn6k/